# elasticsearch how to use preference in node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, preference

I am sending requests from Node.js to ES,
It was fine before I put the "preference" option to the code.
and I am getting the same error : "Unknown key for a VALUE_STRING in [preference]."

my code :
`

```
client
    .search({
        _source: TEST_TILEDS,
        index: TEST_INDEX,
        size: _.isNumber(pageSize) === false ? 20 : pageSize,
        body : {
            min_score: 1,
            query,
            explain: false,
            preference: userUuid,
        },
    })
```

`

I want to use Custom value for preference options like the documents said [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

When I tried in Kibana it worked well with localhost:9200/_search?preference='asdf'
but if I put the preference key value in the inside of {} json like below, then it just doesn't work out.

`

```
GET alias_search_tabling_restaurant_production/_search
{
  "query": {
     "bool":
      blabla 
  },
  "preference": "asdf"  // 
}
```

`

Is there any solution for this?
Thank you in advance.

like I explained above, I tried in Kibana but only url + options worked but not the options in json  or node.js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`queryString`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-connecting.html#client-usage:%7E:text=request.%0ADefault%3A%20null-,querystring,-object%20%2D%20Custom%20querystring), and passing it as a query parameter?

```
client
    .search({
        _source: TEST_TILEDS,
        index: TEST_INDEX,
        size: _.isNumber(pageSize) === false ? 20 : pageSize,
        queryString: {"preference": userUuid},
        body : {
            min_score: 1,
            query,
            explain: false,
            preference: userUuid,
        },
    })
```

Comment: Hi pakio, thank you for your quick support, so I guess I should remove preference: userUuid  in body?

Comment: As far as I could see in the source code, looks like the `preference` parameter is not allowed to set in the body. so it seems like yes.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/04634af5522d8733f5b1fca8a4c4a3fe4c9347de/src/api/api/search.ts#L45

Comment: Oh thank you Pakio! I solved it out with your help.  It supposed to be with the same depth with body not in the inside. Thank you again!